# Close Variable Editor by commands

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to close the Variable Editor from MATLAB by using commands?

I assume that it can be done by getting the properties of the Variable Editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
% Get access to matlab desktop
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance();

% Close the variable editor
desktop.closeGroup('Variables');
```

NB: If you neeed to, use `desktop.getGroupTitles()` to obtain the name for other windows ('Command History', 'Workspace', etc...).

Comment: Not sure why it is needed though, it is much easier to plot variable in command window.